# What is the efficient way of performing "transpose" of a large polars dataframe in python?

Tags: performance, parquet, transpose, python-polars

I am using Polars for the first time. I have a large csv file which has ~0.2 million columns & roughly ~2500 rows. Now, I have to do some parsing or transformation on these columns, however, Polars is faster when there are millions of rows but fewer columns. So I wanted to transpose my polars dataframe so that I can have ~0.2 million rows & ~2500 columns & perform all necessary transformation.

For now, I split my large csv into 500 small chunks of csvs each with size ~2500 rows x ~300 columns & I am running a loops to read these csv files as polars dataframe, do the transpose & save the transposed dataframes into a list.

I read in Polars documentation about converting to [parquet files](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet.html#polars.LazyFrame.sink_parquet) as they take less memory in RAM. However, I am getting pyarrow not installed error.

I am doing the following:

```
import Polars as pl
   
def read_file_asparquet(file):
    df = pl.read_csv(file)
    df.write_parquet('output.parquet', use_pyarrow=True)
    df_trans = df.read_parquet('output.parquet', use_pyarrow=True).transpose(include_header=True, header_name='Actual_cols')
    return df_trans

def read_file(file):
    df = pl.read_csv(file)
    df_trans = df.transpose(include_header=True, header_name='Actual_cols')
    return df_trans

csv_list = ['input1.csv', 'input2.csv',....'input500.csv'] #Each csv size: 2500rows x 500 columns
df_list = list(map(read_file_asparquet, csv_list)) #Throws error
df_newlist = list(map(read_file,csv_list)) #Total time taken = ~5mins
```

However, the above code when I call the function read_file_asparquet throws error: "`pa.Table has no module pyarrow`" --> Though I have successfully installed pyarrow & `import pyarrow` is successful.

I tried below cases alternatively but they are not so efficient:

- When I dont convert to parquet & just do .transpose() after read_csv(), I dont get any error & transposition is successful. The total time taken was: **~5mins 23s (Wall time), CPU time: 9min 23s** .
- When I convert to parquet but dont use "use_pyarrow=True" option during write/read_parquet(), & do transposition, then total time taken is much longer: **Wall time - ~8mins 7s, CPU Time: 17min 43s**

Please let me know the efficient way of doing transpose so that it consumes less memory & time.
Edit1: I have added the code where I am looping over 500 csv files.

Comment: You say that you're doing this in chunks but then your code snippet shows doing it all at once. Put the actual code of you doing it in chunks. Don't assume people can read your mind as to how you're implementing this chunking. It's likely that the problems you're having are in the chunking which you've omitted.

Comment: I am simply using iteration by map to loop over all the chunks. My chunks of csv files or raw data are available or saved in my local directory. Previously I had added only the source code which operates on each chunk & throws the error.

Comment: **1.** - Why are you splitting the CSV file? Can't you read the single file and transpose it? **2.** - `pl.read_csv` vs. `pl.read_parquet` isn't going to make a difference as both read all of the data into memory. **3.** - You say you need to transpose for performance reasons - do you have working code for the non-transposed CSV data that is too slow? What is it you're actually doing?

Comment: Your initial `Transpose assertion` exception should probably [be reported.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/) As for your code example: `import Polars as pl` raises an `ImportError`. `df.read_parquet` raises an `AttributeError`. Fixing these, your code runs without error for me.

Comment: Not directly related but as an example: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/8947 is an issue with `pl.exclude()` in wide dataframes that just received a fix/massive speedup. If you can create a test-case for your original wide-related performance problem, it's possible something can be improved upon.

Answer (score 1):

The intermediate `write -> read` of parquet files doesn't make any sense? This will not save any memory as you read it in memory again.

The `use_pyarrow=True` is also not needed. You can simply write with the polars backed parquet writer.

In any case, I don't really understand your question.

`df.transpose()`

is faster than

`df.write_parquet() -> read_parquet().transpose()`

which is correct, as it saves an intermediate IO operation.

### Conclusion

So the fastest way to transpose a polars dataframe is calling `df.transpose()`.
I cannot make it any simpler.

Comment: Hey ritchie, [the initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76262958/1) was about an exception when using `df.transpose` (without pyarrow) - which is probably why the current edit doesn't make as much sense.

Comment: Hi, I had edited the initial question showing the correct error msg now. And I had changed the question title to make it more generic to focus more on performance improvement. Apologies for the initial question.